# Making HTTP requests from server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, soundcloud

I have some code that is trying to get a JSON result from the Soundcloud API.

I registered an app, got the client id and such, and I'm trying to make a call like this:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

var addr = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=XXXXX';

var options = {
    hostname: "api.soundcloud.com",
    path: "/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=XXXXXx",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}

var request = http.get(options, function(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {

        console.log(chunk);
    });
});
```

This produces a result that looks like this:

```
{"status":"302 - Found","location":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/49931.json?client_id=xxxx"}
```

When I use the same URL in Chrome, I get the proper JSON info. How do I properly make this call from server side script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in http client does not handle redirects. However [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) does and has many other features the built-in client does not support out of the box.

Comment: Oddly enough, I use request extensively and completely blanked on it while trying to get this particular feature working. Thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score -1):

Today I updated my own NodeJS Api-Wrapper Package for Soundcloud, which can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/soundcloud-nodejs-api-wrapper

It does server side API communication, which includes data modification. No user popup window and redirect url is needed.

I did not found yet any other package having support for this in NodeJS.

Comment: This is not an answer to "how to fish ?", to my eyes. This is "here is the fish. Enjoy your meal".